# Примонтировать раздел в readonly-режиме

Tags: linux, linux-mint, диск, монтирование

При попыткие примонтировать раздел через интерфейс проводника получаю ошибку

> #### Не удалось присоединить Data E
>
> Error mounting /dev/sda9 at /media/qwertiy/Data E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda9" "/media/qwertiy/Data E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
> Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
> Failed to mount '/dev/sda9': Operation not permitted
> The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
> Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
> read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Пытаюсь выполнить в командной строке (добавил `-o ro`) в команду из сообщения выше

```
sudo mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" -o ro "/dev/sda9" "/media/qwertiy/Data E"
```

но получаю ошибку

> fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/qwertiy/Data E: Нет такого файла или каталога

Что я делаю не так?
Как примонтировать диск для чтения без перезагрузки в винду?

Comment: Выкинуть пробел всё-таки? Я понимаю, что экранирование. Плюс лично я люблю монтировать в `/windows/{c,d}`. Так точно не возникает конфликтов с почти системными папками `/media` и `/mnt`. И что будет, если использовать `mkdir -p /windows/e && ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda9 /windows/e`?

Comment: @donRumata, а что не так с пробелом? Он из имени ntfs-раздела взят - минт сам так сделал. И эм.. Это ж вроде и есть системная папка media? Почему в неё нельзя монтировать? `ntfs-3g` - это с какой целью? Хм.. А папку в media надо было самому создавать, или как? Если да, то кто её потом удалять должен?

Comment: @donRumata, да, создал папку в другом месте и всё примонтировалось. Ответ напишешь? Желательно поподробнее про `media`. Я ожидал, что там все нужные папки уже есть, а там вообще пусто.

Comment: Да, конечно напишу. Только позже.

Comment: Готово. Каменты выше трём?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо попробовать НЕ монтировать в `/mnt` и `/media` - эти каталоги используются (в той же бубунте больше `media`) для [временного](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=271033.msg2137006#msg2137006) монтирования внешних накопителей. В более старых версиях была схема `/media/метка-тома-или-его-uuid`. Сейчас `/media/$USER/метка-тома-или-его-uuid`. Все подкаталоги создаются и удаляются ОС автоматом. Создавать папки там - чревато вероятными конфликтами имён и ugo. Ещё в старых мануалах за 2007-2009е говорилось, что лучше не надо. 99,9% сработает такой вариант:

godmode:

```
sudo -i
```

Создаём принудительно будущую точку монтирования:

```
mkdir -p /windows/e
```

Монтируем раздел на чтение\запись:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda9 /windows/e
```

Если надо только смотреть, то как-то так:

```
ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda9 /windows/e
```

Если надо монтировать при старте системы - вот так работает на ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04. Строка добавляется в `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=0B0525B62F08257C   /windows/F              ntfs-3g         users,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8,nobootwait 0 0
```

`UUID` узнаётся через `sudo blkid`

Comment: А можно ещё про опции, которые в оригинальной команде использовались? Про `/mnt` не понял - я же могу одновременно несколько флешек подключать. А комменты пусть останутся :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, "в оригинальной" - в твоей или моей? Я перенёс из каментов "как есть". Что именно разъяснить?

Comment: В оригинальной - это из сообщения проводника: `-o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"` - вот это что значит и надо ли его писать, когда монтируешь сам. И ещё вопрос, если к этому приписывать `ro`, то сюда же через запятую `- o "вся-эта-куча,ro"` или ещё одним параметром: `-o "..." -o ro`?

Comment: Дополнил ответ сучётом `fstab`. Не, весь этот мусор для тонкой настройки. В ванили работает с обыными параметрами. По поводу синтаксиса `-o`. Можно так: `-o opt1 -o opt2 -o opt3`, а можно `-o opt1,opt2,opt3`.

Comment: Что-то я не сразу обратил внимание, что в командах `ntfs-3g` вместо `mount`. Оно чем-то лучше?

Comment: @Qwertiy, прямо сейчас возможности проверить нет, но могу сказать по опыту `NFS`. `mount -t nfs` и `mount.nfs` делают одно и тоже. Просто обёртка. Но ntfs-3g писать в консоли быстрее, потому что автодополнение.

Comment: Ага, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

> uhelper=udisks2

Т.е. изначально монтируете раздел не вы, а `udisks2`, обычно вызванный из файлового менеджера. Он и создаёт директории в `/media`, а при ошибке или при размонтировании - удаляет.

При попытке монтировать самостоятельно командой `mount` точка монтирования должна уже существовать. `mount` созданием директорий не занимается. Удалять директорию при необходимости после работы - тоже уже ваша задача будет.