# Проблема записи на HDD c NTFS в Raspbian (GNU\Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, ntfs, raspbian

В `Raspbian Jessie Lite v4.4.26-v7` (если вообще это информация нужна) примонтировал `HDD` с `HTFS`но нет прав на внесения изменения в каталоге `/mnt/MediaServer`

Настройки файла `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID="7E0E9A2B1E99DC29" /mnt/MediaServer ntfs rw,nls=utf8,gid=plugdev,umask=0002 0 0
```

Но при попытки изменения не хватает прав (выполняю под `root` и с `sudo` чтоб наверняка):

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'test': Operation not permitted
bash: text.txt: Permission denied
```

И вывод `ls -Al` (да с правами все очень плохо):

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev 4.0K Nov 15  2014 .GoFlexData
drwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev    0 Nov 15  2014 .GoFlexData_minidlna
drwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev    0 Nov 15  2014 .GoFlexData_thumbs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev 822K Nov 15  2014 .Scanner.log
drwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev    0 Sep  4 18:48 .Trashes
drwxrwxr-x 1 root plugdev    0 Nov 13 20:51 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev    0 Oct 23 22:00 Cloud
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev  16K Nov 12 19:28 Music
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev  20K Nov 13 08:55 System Volume Information
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev    0 Oct 28 18:29 Ubuntu
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev    0 Nov 15  2014 logs
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev    0 Sep 24 08:42 msdownld.tmp
drwxrwxrwx 1 root plugdev 4.0K Nov 13 10:15 ??????????????
```

Comment: Попробуй строку фстаба из этого ответа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584280/191416

Comment: @donRumata добавил данную строку, но проблема осталась, возможно я что-то делаю не так (перемонтировал)   `UUID=7E0E9A2B1E99DC29   /mnt/MediaServer  ntfs-3g  pi,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8,nobootwait 0 0`

Comment: @donRumata не поставил `ntfs-3g`, с ней все работает

Comment: Внимательно перечитай мой ответ. Я там писал по поводу `/mnt` и `/media`. И что за `pi`? 1 в 1 скопируй (ну кроме uuid).

Comment: @donRumata да ваш ответ помог, проблема была в не предустановленном драйвере ntfs-3g.

Comment: Тогда отметь это как-нибудь, чтобы те, кто будет читать этот вопрос позже не перелопачивали всю простыню каментов.

Comment: @donRumata я знаю, но к сожалению в рабочие дни руки не доходят до ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно установить `ntfs-3g`, для этого использую пакетный менеджер `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Отредактировать файл `/etc/fstab`, для начала откроем его:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

Добавить сточку:

```
UUID=7E0E9A2B1E99DC29   /mnt/MediaServer   ntfs-3g   pi,locale=ru_RU.UTF-8,nobootwait 0 0
```

После чего нужно перемонтировать диск с NTFS:

```
# Отмонтировать диск
umount /mnt/MediaServer

# Примонтирвовать 
mount -a
```

> Хочу заметить что для `ntfs` права доступа и владелец прописывается в фале `/etc/fstab`. Хочу упоминуть ответ [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584280/215163) от пользователя [@don-rumata](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191416/don-rumata) который очень помог.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы, находясь в некоторой директории Х пытаетесь создать поддиркторию Y командой:

```
mkdir Y
```

и получаете сообщение

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'Y': Operation not permitted
```

то причина в том, что у Вас нет прав на запись в директори X .
Т.е. Вам необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

```
cd ..
sudo chmod 0777 X
```

После этого Вы сможете создавать поддиректории в X.

Кстати, насколько я помню, в fstab надо указывать тип файловой системы ntfs-3g а не ntfs. Так как драйвер типа ntfs не обеспечивает запись на такой диск. И в системе должен быть установлен драйвер ntfs-3g. Хотя, может быть в современных версиях Linux это уже не обязательно... Точно не знаю!

Comment: В `Raspbian Jessie Lite` не предустановленн `ntfs-3g` и поставил отдельно, и либо я что-то не понимаю но ответ не об этом, проблема не в правах, а в том что установить `ntfs` за место `ntfs-3g`, и возможно только чтения. На данный момент проблему решил.